# Explanation for the "nonew" rule in JSHint

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

There's a rule/option in [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) that I've never clearly understood: the [**nonew**](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#nonew) rule:

> This option prohibits the use of constructor functions for
>   side-effects. Some people like to call constructor functions without
>   assigning its result to any variable:
>
> `new MyConstructor();`
>
> There is no advantage in this approach over
>   simply calling MyConstructor since the object that the operator new
>   creates isn't used anywhere so you should generally avoid constructors
>   like this one.

Here's what I don't understand:

- What's an example of a "side effect" that would result from invoking an object constructor?
- What's the proper way to invoke an object constructor if you have no need to reference the instance as a variable?
- What is meant by saying there is no advantage over calling `MyConstructor()` without `new`? Obviously that wouldn't create an object as intended.

---

To help elicit helpful responses, how should the code below be refactored to instantiate the object when there is no further need for referencing the instance after invoking the constructor?

```
var Module = require('./module');

(function (Module) {

  new Module({
    el: '#module',
    tpl: '#tpl-module',
    status: false
  });

})(Module);
```

Comment: 1. Side-effects considered to be error prone. 2. Why would you need to call a constructor if you are not going to use the newly created object? If the answer is 'side-effect' see 1.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the proper way to invoke an object constructor if you have no need to reference the instance as a variable?

Don't invoke the constructor if you don't need an instance.

> What is meant by saying there is no advantage over calling MyConstructor() without new? Obviously that wouldn't create an object as intended.

If the purpose of the call is to execute side effects, you don't need to create an object. You should use a plain function (I'm tempted to call it "procedure"), instead of a constructor, if you need such.

In case the constructor does use the instance (and binds it somewhere), this is considered a bad practise. The constructor should only create and initialise the object. Everything else should be done in a separate method.